# Floating point issue with SKShapeNode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, floating-point

I am currently encountering a weird floating point issue. Could anyone explain this?

```
import SpriteKit

let height: CGFloat = 20.0
let width: CGFloat = 150.0

let shapeNode: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
print(shapeNode.frame.size.width, shapeNode.frame.size.height) //152.6999969482422 22.700000762939453
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what do you want:

```
import SpriteKit

let height: CGFloat = 20.0
let width: CGFloat = 150.0

let shapeNode: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
shapeNode.isAntialiased = false
shapeNode.lineWidth = 0
print(shapeNode.frame.size.width, shapeNode.frame.size.height) // 150.0 20.0\n
```

Remember:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode

> ... is that shapes are rasterized dynamically at runtime to produce crisp detail and smoother edges.